# how to insert tracking link for shipment in magento from csv

Tags: magento-1.7, php

I have csv having track number, order number, carrier name and tracking link now i want to insert tracking link for shipment in magento from csv

```
if (($handle = fopen("".$webshopimport_path."\\CSV\\trackandtrace.csv", "r")) !== FALSE)
{
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 100000, ",")) !== FALSE)
    {
        Mage::init();
        $comment = null;
        $email = false;
        $includeComment = false;
        $orderId = $data[5];                                                        //get ordernumber from csv
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
        $convertor = Mage::getModel('sales/convert_order');
        $shipment = $convertor->toShipment($order);

        foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $orderItem)
        {
            if (!$orderItem->getQtyToShip()) {
                continue;
            }
            if ($orderItem->getIsVirtual()) {
                continue;
            }
            $item = $convertor->itemToShipmentItem($orderItem);
            $qty = $orderItem->getQtyToShip();
            $item->setQty($qty);
            $shipment->addItem($item);
        }

        $trackdata = array();
        $trackdata['carrier_code'] = $data[2];                                   //get carrier_code from csv
        $trackdata['title'] = $data[2];                                          //get title from csv
        $trackdata['number'] = $data[3];                                         //get track number from csv
        $trackdata['track_link'] = $data[4];                                         //get track link from csv


        $track = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment_track')->addData($trackdata);
        $shipment->addTrack($track);
        //echo "<pre>"; print_r($shipment);echo "<pre>"; exit;

        Mage::register('current_shipment', $shipment);

        $shipment->register();
        $shipment->addComment($comment, $email && $includeComment);
        $shipment->setEmailSent(true);
        $shipment->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);
        echo "<pre>"; print_r($shipment);echo "<pre>"; exit;

        $transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
            ->addObject($shipment)
            ->addObject($shipment->getOrder())
            ->save();

        $shipment->sendEmail($email, ($includeComment ? $comment : ''));
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

I am able to save track number, carrier name but not to save tracking link, please help me for this query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know adding the `tracking_link` is not a default feature of Magento. I took a look at the model and especially the database (as shown below) and there don't seem to be any fields for that.

[image]

Are you using some custom extension for tracking shipments?

Comment: I am new to use magento, i try out with adding field in above table and data goes inserted in that now i want to fetch track_number, track_link, carrier_code, created_at and want to show it on from side (tracktrace.phtml)

Comment: if i need to create custom attribute then please suggest me way for the same.

Comment: You should be able to call this value from the model `Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment_track')->load([ID])->getData('track_link');` if you've added the column in the database